# Is an audio equalizer available for Linux Mint 18.3?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio-equalizer

I have Googled myself into near exhaustion trying to find an audio equalizer for Linux Mint 18.3. The only advice I've found is for older versions of LM or Ubuntu, *none of which work for me*.

I recently moved my best stereo speakers (with subwoofer) from a seldom-used XP Pro PC to this LM MATE 18.3 machine, and their sound quality is nowhere near what it was on the XP box! To think that that no equalizer is available --either graphical or command-line-based-- is almost unthinkable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installed PulseEffects in Software Manager. Solved! :-)

[image: PulseEffects from LM MATE 18.3 Software Manager]

[image: PulseEffects equalizer section]

Comment: This is nice, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @acoder Glad you liked it, thanks! However, on Stack Exchange it is customary to upvote an answer in lieu of a comment. :-)

Comment: I did both hope that is ok

Answer (score 1):

For PulseAudio there's **qpaeq** in the **pulseaudio-equalizer** package.

For raw ALSA there's **libasound2-plugin-equal** which can be adjusted via **alsamixer**.

Comment: Thanks, but qpaeq or pulseaudio-equalizer do not seem to be compatible with LM 18.3. Neither is in Synaptic; however, libasound2-plugin-equal is. I just installed PulseEffects in Software Manager and will try it first.

Comment: Okay, libasound2-plugin-equal installed. However, I see no equalizer option in alsamixer; it looks the same as it did before.

Comment: **DUH!** PulseEffects WORKS *if the volume control on the speakers is not turned fully CCW*. ;-)

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Perhaps someone else running Linus Mint MATE 18.3 can get your suggestions to work, and post their experiences here. Keep in mind that LM does not necessarily have the latest package updates, as Clem's emphasis is on stability.